# Spring social linkedin - trouble with org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.withSerializationInclusion

Tags: java, spring, linkedin-api, spring-social

I'm using spring social in my project. I already completed integration with facebook and twitter, but had trouble with linkedin.

if I try create connection:

```
Connection <LinkedIn> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessToken);
```

then I have this exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.withSerializationInclusion(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize$Inclusion;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig;

I already tried use different versions of spring-social-linkedin and different version of jackson lib (v 1.9.2 and above) but unsuccessful.

Can anyone tell me how resolve this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

The method is available [since v1.9](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.html#withSerializationInclusion%28org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion%29) of the API.

The only reason this can happen is that you are compiling against the right libraries at compile time, but at runtime this method is unavailable. There is a stale version (< 1.9) of the library on your classpath somewhere.

```
withSerializationInclusion

public SerializationConfig withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion incl)
Since:
1.9
```

Comment: i checked all pom file and didn't find using of stale version of the lib. War file contain only one version of jackson lib - jackson-core-asl-1.9.3.jar   and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.3.jar. But trouble are still exist.

Comment: What about the server classpath ? The stale jar may not be loaded by your WAR but by a parent classloader.